# Firebird IF ELSE

Tags: if-statement, firebird

I have this line in my query:

```
IF (TEST_DESC CONTAINING 'OPEN') THEN TEST_DESC = 'OPEN';
```

but that is not working. Firebird says **Can't Prepare , because  query is empty**,
when I remove the **;** it says **Token unknown - line 8, column 10.
(.**

I want to use IF ELSE to look if the **TEST_DESC** field contains **OPEN**, if it has, it will output the word **OPEN** in the field. The TEST_DESC field contains **SCL_OPEN** I only want to show the **OPEN**. And the other one is that the other value contains **DRV_SHORT**, and I want to show **SHORT** only.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF/THEN/ELSE is a [PSQL construct](http://www.janus-software.com/fbmanual/manual.php?book=PSQL&topic=98).

For a plain SQL query, which I infer you're using from your syntax error, use a [CASE statement](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html):

```
...
CASE
WHEN TEST_DESC LIKE '%OPEN%'
     THEN 'OPEN'
WHEN TEST_DESC LIKE '%SHORT%'
     THEN 'SHORT'
ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
END
...
```

There is also an [IIF()](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-iif.html) function with approximately the syntax you want:  `IIF(TEST_DESC CONTAINING 'FOO', 'FOO', 'NO FOO')`.

See also this [Firebird FAQ entry](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq294/).